# proxy-public not coming up in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, jupyterhub

I used the following terraform [link](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks) to create an EKS cluster. Then followed the steps outlined [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/jupyterhub/installation.html#install-jupyterhub) to install jupyterhub.
However, the proxy-public service doesnt come up

```
kubectl describe svc proxy-public -n jhub
Name:                     proxy-public
Namespace:                jhub
Labels:                   app=jupyterhub
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=jupyterhub-0.10.6
                          component=proxy-public
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=jhub
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: jhub
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: jhub
Selector:                 component=proxy,release=jhub
Type:                     LoadBalancer
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From                Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----                -------
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer    2m40s (x10 over 22m)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  2m40s (x10 over 22m)  service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

I have already verified that the subnets are tagged correctly as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/)

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets  --query "Subnets[].[SubnetID,Tags[]]" --output text
None
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
kubernetes.io/role/elb  1
Name    dev-vpc-public-us-west-2c
None    None
None
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
kubernetes.io/role/elb  1
Name    dev-vpc-public-us-west-2a
None
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb 1
Name    dev-vpc-private-us-west-2c
None
Name    dev-vpc-private-us-west-2b
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb 1
None    None
None    None
None    None
None
Name    dev-vpc-public-us-west-2b
kubernetes.io/role/elb  1
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
None
Name    dev-vpc-private-us-west-2a
kubernetes.io/cluster/education-eks-ZPQBVzm1    shared
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb 1
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, apparently the [terraform template](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks) here is wrong. It attaches a different *cluster_name* tag to the subnet (in vpc.tf)

```
locals {
  cluster_name = "education-eks-${random_string.suffix.result}"
}
```

I wanted a different name, so i had modified the *cluster_name* in the eks.tf. I should have modified this local instead